# Extract Multi Values to Points for two time-enabled layers using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, point, extract, time

I have a time-enabled point layer (5-minute resolution) and time-enabled raster layer (hourly resolution). I'm trying to create a new field in the point layer by extracting values, but it's doing so for only one hour of the raster layer.

For example, if I have points for 12pm, 1pm, 2pm it's assigning the 12pm raster value to all three points rather than synchronizing the time for both layers in the process.

Is there a way to extract values so that the new field contains the raster value for the specific hour?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the Question to detail the exact procedure you are using the extract the data. A screenshot from before pressing "Ok" and/or the Geoprocessing result log would be useful information.